# Python - formating numbers of an ascii table

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, numbers, text-files

I wonder why my code does not work. I want to round a two column data just with 2 numbers after decimal point. I am following at this moment the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open('input.dat', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in f:
        try:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            vx = float(columns[0])
            vy = float(columns[1])
            print("{:.2f\t}".format(vx),"{:.2f}".format(vy), file=outfile)
        except ValueError:
            print(line, file=outfile)
```

The input data is like following

```
XY
HH
M&M
TS
1.83746 2.12131
1.12121 1.89942
1.32435 1.99443
1.65392 2.00001
1.48732 2.21773
...
...
```

the output should be like following:

```
XY
HH
M&M
TS
1.84    2.12
1.12    1.90
1.32    1.99
1.65    2.00
1.49    2.22
...
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this line is wrong

```
print("{:.2f\t}".format(vx),"{:.2f}".format(vy), file=outfile)
```

The tab should be outside of the `{}` and I would rewrite it like this

```
print("{:.2f}\t{:.2f}".format(vx, vy), file=outfile)
```